# SQL join and add nulls

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one looks like:

```
ID    VALUE    DATE
1       A      2020-01-02 12:00
2       B      2020-01-03 10:00
```

And another that looks like:

```
ID    VALUE    DATE
1       2      2020-01-02 12:00
1       3      2020-02-01 12:00
3       2      2020-02-03 12:00
```

I would like to join them and have the result look like:

```
ID    VALUE1    VALUE1_DATE        VALUE2       VALUE2_DATE
1        A     2020-01-02 12:00      2         2020-01-02 12:00
1                                    3         2020-02-01 12:00
2        B     2020-01-03 10:00
3                                    2         2020-02-03 12:00
```

Where if the id and dates match they are together on one row but if they don't they are on their own row with NULLS for the other values. Is this possible with just a join or do I need to do it within a case when statement?

Comment: Looks like a job for an `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: "but if they don't they are on their own row with NULLS for the other values" - what are their own rows?

Comment: full outer join

Comment: For example the first row in the example result, ID 1 has a value on the first and second table with the same data, so I want them together in the row.

Comment: @GNMO11 match case was clear... I didn't get for the case when there are no match... should there be some special order or not?

Comment: @demo order by dates

Comment: I'd expect second row as `(1        A     2020-01-02 12:00      3         2020-02-01 12:00)`.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand question correctly, solution can looks like this

```
SELECT ISNULL(t1.ID, t2.ID), t1.VALUE as VALUE1, t1.DATE as DATE1, t2.VALUE as VALUE2, t2.DATE as DATE2
FROM TEST1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN TEST2 t2
   ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.DATE = t2.DATE
ORDER BY ISNULL(t1.ID, t2.ID), t1.DATE, t2.DATE
```

Here join by ID and Date... but in result you want to see only one `ID` column,  so I used `ISNULL` function to show non-nullable id from tables.

---

Solution for SQL SERVER

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Also, this will give a result that probably makes sense, but it will not be the same as the question has specied - probably better!